# Maven MOJO - use a parameter in another parameter

Tags: java, maven, mojo

Is it possible to use a defined parameter in another parameter? For example I tried this and figured out this is not allowed:

```
@Parameter(required = true)
private String semester;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "${basedir}/src/main/resources/" + semester)
private String inputFolder;
```

My second try was to put use the parameter as expression:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${basedir}/src/main/resources/${semester}")
private String inputFolder;
```

This was also a fail. The next iteration: I wrote the parameter as property at plugin's execution:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
private MavenProject project;

@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{
    Properties props = project.getProperties();
    props.put("semester", semester);
}
```

This doesn't work either, because the parameters are injected before `execute()` is executed. The only solution I get to is to replace the expressions by myself:

```
inputFolder = inputFolder.replace("${semester}", semester);
outputFolder = outputFolder.replace("${semester}", semester);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already discover: no, you can't reuse it like this.
The code suggest that there's a variable folder for a semester (do you really need to reuse it?). That's kind of weird: just point the `inputDirectory` to the correct folder, make that parameter required. 
Less obvious solution is to do it in code:

```
File semesterFolder = new File( inputFolder, semester);
```

Ensure that you document the parameters very well, like how the semester parameter is used to get this folder.